# html form to txt with php

Tags: php, html, easyphp

idk why but its just dont work for me..

**this is in index.html**

```
<form action="myprocessingscript.php" method="POST">
    <input name="field1" type="text" />
    <input name="field2" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data">
</form>
```

**in myprocessingscript.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2'])) {
    $data = $_POST['field1'] . '-' . $_POST['field2'] ."\n";
    $ret = file_put_contents('log.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    if($ret === false) {
        die('There was an error writing this file');
    }
    else {
        echo "$ret bytes written to file";
    }
}
else {
   die('no post data to process');
}
?>
```

log.txt exist..

any one have an idea ?

Comment: Check filepaths and permissions.

Comment: If you are on a unix/linux machine look at permissions

Comment: Try removing LOCK_EX

Comment: Do you have any error?

Comment: blank page. using mac.